# With jQuery how do I handle a "text" response using the bind event?

Tags: jquery

While I am using Rails, this does not appear to be a Rails issue. My XHR is just a simple text string and here's my js:

```
$('form[data-update-target]').bind('ajax:success', function(evt, data) {
 var target = $(this).data('update-target');
 $('#' + target).html(data);
});
```

I "thought" I read in a forum that jQuery tries to determine mime type and it can affect how some of the methods work. Is it possible to handle just text?

Comment: used on() instead of bind method....bind() is deprecated in jquery

Comment: Are you sure that a form has an `ajax:success event`?  How are you triggering the ajax call?

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I was originally using .live() and another post recommended switching to .bind(). Should I still be using .bind()? or is this what .ajaxSuccess() is for?

Comment: @jfriend00 how do I tell if the form has that event? I'm sorry, really new to jQuery. If I render a proper text/html partial, the method is called; but if I use a text response *nothing* gets called.